# Pine Script: Plot Only Selected Range

Tags: plot, range, pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to allow a user to set a specified range of candles back from the current candle, then plot an area graph only from 'close' values in that range.

I can't figure out how to make the new plot start only from the selected candle.

User sets range
`range = input(title="Range Window", type=input.integer, defval=20, minval=1)`

Volume from previous close
`long_volume = iff(overridesym == true, long_security("1",close), close)`

This is the part I don't know...
`plot(long_volume, (over the length of 'range'), style=plot.style_area,)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `show_last` parameter

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
i = input.int(20)
plot(close, show_last=i)
```

Comment: This works to just limit the window of the larger plot.

However, how can I reset the plot to 0 at the user specified [range] so only data from the specified range will populate the range graph?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your case correctly, but you cannot change the value of plots that have already been drawn on historical bars. Do you just want to reset the value of your plot every N bars from first bar?

Comment: The more I've looked into this, the more I'm learning. 
 
I now realize you can't change the value of a bar once, it's been drawn. 
  
I've now resorted to printing a new bar based on data x bars back and then offsetting the new printed  bar over the original bar x bars back.
  
Now I'm trying to figure out how to repeat that action over the following bar sequentially from the user set range up until the current bar.

Comment: Here is a link to where I posted another question about that...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671542/loop-plot-pine-script